# Passenger Rails url prefix causing no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, httpd.conf

I have a Rails application that is rooted inside a folder called convergeops. My Phusion Passenger is setup to serve the `PassengerBaseURI` to `/convergeops`.

80% of the time, everything works fine, but every now and then I get a `No route matches` error as shown below:

[image]

#### httpd.conf file

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/convergeops/public"

<Directory "/var/www/html/convergeops">
  RailsEnv production
  PassengerBaseURI /convergeops
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/convergeops
  SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT /convergeops
  PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
  AllowOverride all
  Allow from all
  Options -MultiViews
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any idea why I might be getting this routing error?

Comment: I've had this problem before too. I ended up ditching the prefixed url. I'm curious to see what the solution is though?